# add printer for my application

Tags: c#, network-printers

I want to add a printer for my application to the network printers list.I mean something like what Adobe PDF do.

I could get all printers in the network by the following code :

```
// Use the ObjectQuery to get the list of configured printers
System.Management.ObjectQuery oquery =
new System.Management.ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");

System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher mosearcher =
new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(oquery);

System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mosearcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
{
    lstPrinter.Items.Add(mo["Name"]);
}
```

I do not know what should i search to find this.please help ...

Comment: Please refer the below link [http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/managing-printers-programatically-using-c-and-wmi/](http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/managing-printers-programatically-using-c-and-wmi/)

Answer (score 0):

See [Command Line Printer Control](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/2kprintcontrol.php). You can run this code by `Procces.Start(...)`:

```
rundll32.exe printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /?
```

and this link of Microsoft support can be useful:

- [How to add printers with no user interaction in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314486)

If you consist on using WMI, the [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) tool can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply, I will try your solution and call back the result.

Comment: @M_Mogharrabi: salam. khahesh!

Comment: salam!!!!!! bebakhshid man dir be dir miam javabamo check mikonam.in soal ro baraye dostam porsidam, hanooz check nakarde.be nazare shoma WMI behtare?